# cURL login into Linkbucks

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I'm trying to make a script that log in into my Linkbucks account to get my current stats.

They provide and api, but only for creating links, what I need is you get the statistics.

Things I discovered:

1. First, you have to stay logged
2. To get the stats, the website makes a ajax call to: https://www.linkbucks.com/Profile.aspx?task=manageLinks&action=loadPublisherStats with a JSON post like this: {"month":"09/01/2015"} .

With this post its easy to get the information I need, the problem is that my script is not working.

I share the code with you, so please help me.

Any idea or solution, or whatever will be appreciated.

Here is my script:

```
<?php

$urlLogin = "https://www.linkbucks.com/Default.aspx";

$ch = getSource($urlLogin);
$fuente = curl_exec($ch);

$re = "/<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATE\" id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"(.*?)\" \\/>/";  
preg_match($re, $fuente, $matches);

$re = "/<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" id=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"(.*?)\" \\/>/";  
preg_match($re, $fuente, $validation);

$re = "/<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR\" id=\"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR\" value=\"(.*?)\" \\/>/";  
preg_match($re, $fuente, $generator);

$post = array(
    "ctl00\$ctl00\$phMenu\$LeftMenuBar\$ctl00\$Username" => "yourusername" , 
    "ctl00\$ctl00\$phMenu\$LeftMenuBar\$ctl00\$Password" => "yourpassword" ,
    "__VIEWSTATE" => $matches[1] , 
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" => $generator[1] ,
    "__EVENTVALIDATION" => $validation[1]
);
$data = postData($urlLogin, $post);

echo $data;

function getSource($url, $header = null) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $config['useragent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.33 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/9.10 Chromium/13.0.752.0 Chrome/13.0.752.0 Safari/534.33';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $config['useragent']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, (is_null($header) ? 'https://www.google.com/' : $header));
    return $ch;
}

function postData($url , $array) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($array));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.linkbucks.com/Default.aspx");

    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.linkbucks.com/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fManageLinks');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

    return ($server_output);
}

?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I wasn't getting any errors, just the code isn't working, but now is solved!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, thanks to **runz0rd** I was able to make the code work!!

Thank you so much guys!!

Here is the final version of the code:

```
<?php

$urlLogin = "https://www.linkbucks.com/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fManageLinks";
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.33 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/9.10 Chromium/13.0.752.0 Chrome/13.0.752.0 Safari/534.33';
$source = getSource($urlLogin, $useragent);

$viewstate = findStringByRegex("/<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATE\" id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"(.*?)\" \/>/", $source);
$generator = findStringByRegex("/<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR\" id=\"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR\" value=\"(.*?)\" \\/>/", $source);
$validation = findStringByRegex("/<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" id=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"(.*?)\" \\/>/", $source);


$post = array(
    'ctl00$ctl00$phMenu$LeftMenuBar$ctl00$Username' => "yourusername",
    'ctl00$ctl00$phMenu$LeftMenuBar$ctl00$Password' => "yourpassword",
    'ctl00$ctl00$phMenu$LeftMenuBar$ctl00$LoginImgBtn.x' => 0,
    'ctl00$ctl00$phMenu$LeftMenuBar$ctl00$LoginImgBtn.y' => 0,
    "__VIEWSTATE" => $viewstate,
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" => $generator,
    "__EVENTVALIDATION" => $validation
);
$data = postData($urlLogin, $post);

echo $data;

function getSource($url, $useragent = null, $header = null) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, (is_null($header) ? 'https://www.google.com/' : $header));

    return curl_exec($ch);
}

function postData($url, $postArray) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postArray));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.linkbucks.com/Default.aspx");

    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.linkbucks.com/Profile.aspx?task=manageLinks&action=loadPublisherStats");
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    $fecha = json_encode( array( "month"=> "09/01/2015" ) );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fecha );
    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

    return $server_output;
}

function findStringByRegex($regex, $source) {
    preg_match($regex, $source, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$urlLogin = "https://www.linkbucks.com/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fManageLinks";
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.33 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/9.10 Chromium/13.0.752.0 Chrome/13.0.752.0 Safari/534.33';
$source = getSource($urlLogin, $useragent);

$viewstate = findStringByRegex("/<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATE\" id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"(.*?)\" \/>/", $source);
$generator = findStringByRegex("/<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR\" id=\"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR\" value=\"(.*?)\" \\/>/", $source);
$validation = findStringByRegex("/<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" id=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"(.*?)\" \\/>/", $source);


$post = array(
    'ctl00$ctl00$phMenu$LeftMenuBar$ctl00$Username' => "yourUsername",
    'ctl00$ctl00$phMenu$LeftMenuBar$ctl00$Password' => "yourPassword",
    'ctl00$ctl00$phMenu$LeftMenuBar$ctl00$LoginImgBtn.x' => 0,
    'ctl00$ctl00$phMenu$LeftMenuBar$ctl00$LoginImgBtn.y' => 0,
    "__VIEWSTATE" => $viewstate,
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" => $generator,
    "__EVENTVALIDATION" => $validation
);
$data = postData($urlLogin, $post);

echo $data;

function getSource($url, $useragent = null, $header = null) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, (is_null($header) ? 'https://www.google.com/' : $header));

    return curl_exec($ch);
}

function postData($url, $postArray) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArray);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.linkbucks.com/Default.aspx");

    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

    return $server_output;
}

function findStringByRegex($regex, $source) {
    preg_match($regex, $source, $matches);

    return $matches[1];
}
```

Ive cleaned up your code a bit, it was mostly good, you were just missing 2 post fields: ctl00$ctl00$phMenu$LeftMenuBar$ctl00$LoginImgBtn.x and ctl00$ctl00$phMenu$LeftMenuBar$ctl00$LoginImgBtn.y'

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I have completed it with the POST info to get the JSON response and it's working fine. I really appreciate it, really, thank you :)